# IE8 Cross domain Ajax call issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rss

Hello so I've scawered the site on trying to find out what my issue is but have not had any luck.

So what I'm trying to do is an ajax call to pull in a RSS feed

One issue I had was that the feed doesn't have CORs enabled so I'm using this script to get around that.

**github:** https://github.com/padolsey-archive/jquery.fn/blob/master/cross-domain-ajax/jquery.xdomainajax.js

Everything works fine in Firefox Chrome and IE9+

Just IE8 which isn't functioning 100%

So the data gets called but the text for the anchor tag isn't showing up but the link works

any suggestions would be grateful

What I've tried with different variations:

```
var $xml = $($.parseXML(data.responseText));
```

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src='jquery.xdomainajax.js'></script>
</head>

<body>

    <style>
        #feed-results a {
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
    <h1>Feed Contents</h1>
    <div id="feed-results">

    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="feedParser.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            feedParser.getFeedContents('http://aon.mediaroom.com/news-releases?pagetemplate=rss&category=821');
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**ajax call:**

```
var feedParser = (function($) {
    function getFeedContents(url) {
        $.ajax({
            url: $.trim(url),
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.responseText);
                var $xml = $(data.responseText);
                $xml.each(function(index, value) {
                    var regex = /<link>(.*?)<\/link>/ig,
                        links = regex.exec(value);
                    $this = $(value),
                        selitem = {
                            title: $this.find("title").text(),
                            link: links[1],
                            description: $this.find("description").text(),
                            pubDate: $this.find("pubDate").text(),
                            guid: $this.find("guid").text()
                        }
                    $('#feed-results').append(' <ul> <a href=" ' + selitem['link'] + ' "> ' + selitem['title'] + ' </a> </ul> ');
                });
            }
        });
    }

    return {
        'getFeedContents': getFeedContents
    }
})(jQuery);
```

**XML Doc:** (Pulling the feed/This is just the source)
**Feed link:** http://aon.mediaroom.com/news-releases?pagetemplate=rss&category=821

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>News Releases | Aon (Aon Benfield)</title>
        <link>http://aon.mediaroom.com/</link>
        <description>Aon plc Global Media Relations</description>
        <item>
            <title>ILS records continue to tumble as innovation heralds $1.7bn first quarter issuance, according to Aon Benfield study</title>
            <link>http://aon.mediaroom.com/index.php?s=25776&amp;item=137214</link>
            <description></description>
            <pubDate>Wed, 15 Apr 2015 12:01:00 -0400</pubDate>
            <guid>http://aon.mediaroom.com/index.php?s=25776&amp;item=137214</guid>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>March windstorms cause billion-dollar damage across Europe, according to Aon catastrophe study</title>
            <link>http://aon.mediaroom.com/2015-04-08-March-windstorms-cause-billion-dollar-damage-across-Europe-according-to-Aon-catastrophe-study</link>
            <description>Windstorm Niklas recorded as costliest non-U.S. event in first quarter 2015</description>
            <pubDate>Wed, 08 Apr 2015 11:46:00 -0400</pubDate>
            <guid>http://aon.mediaroom.com/2015-04-08-March-windstorms-cause-billion-dollar-damage-across-Europe-according-to-Aon-catastrophe-study</guid>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Global reinsurer capital continues to build to USD575 billion, according to the latest Aon Benfield Aggregate study</title>
            <link>http://aon.mediaroom.com/index.php?s=25776&amp;item=137202</link>
            <description>Alternative capital increases 28% to USD64 billion</description>
            <pubDate>Mon, 30 Mar 2015 12:28:00 -0400</pubDate>
            <guid>http://aon.mediaroom.com/index.php?s=25776&amp;item=137202</guid>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Aon comments on Budget 2015 </title>
            <link>http://aon.mediaroom.com/index.php?s=25776&amp;item=137196</link>
            <description></description>
            <pubDate>Wed, 18 Mar 2015 12:46:00 -0400</pubDate>
            <guid>http://aon.mediaroom.com/index.php?s=25776&amp;item=137196</guid>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Evolving solvency regimes create further opportunities for Asia insurers</title>
            <link>http://aon.mediaroom.com/index.php?s=25776&amp;item=137188</link>
            <description></description>
            <pubDate>Thu, 12 Mar 2015 05:22:00 -0400</pubDate>
            <guid>http://aon.mediaroom.com/index.php?s=25776&amp;item=137188</guid>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

Comment: sounds like a css problem if html with clickable links are being rendered. Try inspecting the live css in dev tools

Comment: yeah I've tried that, I'm not sure maybe there is an issue with .append and IE8